# Get Value Variable of Class PHP

Tags: php

i have class look like this:

```
class MyClass
{
   public $value;
   public function __construct()
   {
      //some code...
   }
   public function setValue()
   {
     $this->value = 1;
   }
}

    $c = new MyClass;
    $c->setValue();
    var_dump(get_object_vars($c));
```

it works but for now, I want to get the value but do not need to declare the class MyClass and call setValue. Somebody can help me?

Comment: Why don't you want to declare MyClass? How are you going to use this class? That determines how you are going to write it.

Comment: Sounds like you might [must want a `static` property](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: If you set `public $value = '1';` then you could create a static method like this: `public static function getValue() { return $this->value; }` and get the value like statically (without writing `new MyClass`: `echo MyClass::getValue()`

Answer (score 0):

### You could make use of the [`ReflectionMethod::invoke`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invoke.php) for this without altering your class structure.

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    public $value;
    public function __construct()
    {
        //some code...
    }
    public function setValue()
    {
        return $this->value = 1;  //<----- Add a return keyword
    }
}
$reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod('MyClass', 'setValue');
echo $reflectionMethod->invoke(new MyClass(), '');
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
1
```

Comment: I don't see how this approach makes sense. IMHO showing code just because someone requests it is bad, when that code should not be used in real applications. In that case, you should really explain a better solution.

Comment: OP wants not the redeclare anything.. so making it as a `static` is breaking his expectations , so the `Reflections` are the good way to go.

Comment: But for this example it makes no sense to use reflection.